# Pandas get closest location

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, distance, geo

I have a dataset containing information about different locations. Each location should be a unique city, but some entries resemble the same city. Those entries have different names (maybe caused by an typoo) and different longitude and latitude (an entrie is created by clicking on a map and saving the geo codes at this spot). I know want to filter entries for the same city to clean up the data.

This is an example table:

```
Name        OrderID Longitude Latitude
New York    123     35.73     40.57
Berlin      222     -12.12    24.67
Neww York   321     35.74     41.01
```

In this case New York is duplicated.
The Output should in some way help me identify those two entries as potentially related.

Is there any way to find cities that could be the same, by comparing the geo data and calculating close by cities?

Comparing the city name is not an option.

I have thought about using three points on the globe like 0.0/0.0 and calculate the distance for each entry to each city and then group them. But I am not sure how this solution might look like and if it would solve my problem.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: By distance between citiies do you mean length of path along loxodrome xor orthodrome?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, if I understood the concept of loxodrome and orthodrome, but I am using the haversine function for calculation meaning shortest distance along orthodrome.

Comment: example has double new york. is it corrent? and can you make desired output of example?

Comment: @PandaKim correct. I tried to update the question regarding an desired output, but I am really free in the way the similarity is  detected.

Comment: ah... i got it. maybe need something like geojson